# Loading multiple instances from DB by a list of primary keys with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, primary-key

Is there an elegant way to load many entities from the database with SqlAlchemy if I have a list of composite primary keys?

One object can be loaded with `Query.get(*primary_key)`. 
What about a list of them? For instance:

```py
primary_keys = [
    {"type":"user", "id": 1},
    {"type":"user", "id": 2},
    {"type":"user", "id": 3},
]

instances = ssn.query(models.Object)#...?
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over `inspect(models.Object).primary_key` and build a condition manually:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_, and_, inspect

instances = ssn.query(models.Object).filter(or_(  # or_()ed together
    # and_()ed condition on all PK fields
    and_(*(
        # column == value
        column == pk_dict[column.key]
        for column in inspect(models.Object).primary_key  # list of PK columns
    ))
    for pk_dict in primary_keys
))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution by @vdmit11 that uses SQL tuples:

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect, tuple_

# List of Column objects of the primary key
pk_columns = inspect(models.Object).primary_key
pk_names = [col.key for col in pk_columns]

# Build the condition: (primary-key-tuple) IN (....)
condition = tuple_(*pk_columns).in_(
    # Every object is represented by its primary key tuple
    tuple(entity_dict[pk_field] for pk_field in pk_names)
    for entity_dict in primary_keys
)

instances = ssn.query(models.Object).filter(condition).all()
```

It will generate a query which looks like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE (uid, login) IN ((1, 'vdmit11'), (2, 'kolypto'));
```